# Are local representations of an automorphic representation always infinite dimensional?

Tags: representation-theory, automorphic-forms

We know an irreducible admissible automorphic representation $\pi$ of $GL_2$ decomposes to tensor product of local representations, and almost every local representation is spherical. To define the L function of $\pi$, I need to know every local spherical representation is in spherical principle series rather than $1$-dimensional. How to show that is true? Maybe this follows from existence of Whittaker model, but I don't know how to rule out the $1$-dimension possibility .

Comment: Yes 1-dimensional representations are not generic, so if you are globally generic, you cannot have a 1-dimensional local component.  On the other hand, you can get 1-dimensional local components working on a quaternion division algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

1. If $\pi$ is an irreducible finite dimensional smooth representation of $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with $G$ reductive and split (note that reductive implies that irreducible+smooth implies admissible in general, but we're finite dimensional here so this is a non-issue) then $\pi$ is a character.
2. It is certainly not true that irreducible spherical representations are $1$-dimensional. I think what you mean is that if $K_0\subseteq G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is hyperspecial, and $\pi$ is a $K_0$-spherical representation of $G(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ then $\pi^{K_0}$ is $1$-dimensional. This follows from the fact (deduced from the Satake isomorphism) that the spherical Hecke algebra is commutative.
3. This last fact (that $K_0$-spherical representations are unramified prinicipal series) is true. See Theorem 3.8 of Cartier's Corvallis article, or Theorem 1.2.12 of Blasius and Rogawski's article in *Motives* Vol. II. I think in the Cartier article he gives a reference to the original general proof due to Casselman.

**EDIT:** To address the question in the comments if you look at [this](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/adelic_mod_forms.pdf) nice note you can find that if $f$ is a cuspform of level $\Gamma_1(N)$ with associated automorphic representation $\pi_f$ then $(\pi_f)_v$ is an unramified principal series for $p\nmid N$

Comment: Thank you, I mean there are two possibilities for irreducible spherical representations: 1-dim or infinite dimensional. An unramified 1-dim rep is spherical by definition. How do we know local reps of global automorphic one are not 1-dim?

Comment: @zzy See the edit. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @zzy You asked for an example, didn't you? I gave an example for where it's not necessarily true that the local representation is $1$-dimensional. It's also true that they can be one dimension by taking an adelic character. I'm not sure what you're asking (also ping me so I know you responded).

Comment: Thank you, I believe that for any irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL_2(\mathbb A)$, every local representation is infinite dimensional.

Comment: @zzy Oh, then do you know that all cuspforms for $\mathrm{GL}_2$ look like the form I stated? E.g. see this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267378/newform-of-a-cuspidal-automorphic-representation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92920/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-zzy).

Comment: @zzy I added some more to that chat.

Comment: Maybe this was resolved in chat, but I read the question as asking how do you know you don't get 1-dimensional reps as local components.

Comment: @Kimball It may have been, but you are certainly far more an expert than I. Essentially the conclusion to the question the OP wanted to ask is yes, I believe, for $\mathrm{GL}_n$ (he was asking about cuspidals) essentially (using big results, I think) because of the genericity result of Shalika and Piatetski-Shapiro (??). Does that sound right to you? Would love to hear your further thoughts! Please feel free to post an alternative answer if you think it's worth it!

Comment: Well, I already said what I wanted to in a comment on the question.  And yes, that's right, the standard argument for cuspidal reps of GL(n) is to use genericity.  Alternatively you can use strong approximation for SL(n) to conclude being locally 1-dimensional somewhere means you are globally 1-dimensional.

Comment: @Kimball Sorry for asking here, but do you mind if I actually ask you the best resource to learn about global representation theory beyond (and perhaps still including some of) the basics, and for general $G$? There so, so many resources to learn about $p$-adic representations but surprisingly few places (I've found) to learn about the general theory of global automorphic representations from a representation theoretic perspective (save, perhaps, the upcoming book of Getz and Hahn). Thanks!

Comment: @Kimball Just as an example, this question of the OP is not really entirely obvious, but seems like it should be included in the material on a 'well-known book' on the subject, but I don't know an actual reference. The type of text I'm asking about might, for example, include this as an example of the theory. One with lots of examples, etc. Something that is a bit Kottwitzian also, if that makes sense. Sorry again for asking for a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't of any great options for general $G$.  Part of the issue of course is that the theory is not so easy and goes in many different directions (trace formulas, integral representations, Eisenstein series, ...).  The only thing I can suggest is read a bunch of surveys (e.g., I have an [old list](http://www.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/afrefs.html)) and then papers when you need details.  I don't remember, but I feel like the genericity argument for the OP's question for GL(2) should be discussed in Gelbart or Bump or Goldfeld.

Comment: @Kimball Thanks for the suggestions anyways! Even for some specific groups (like GL(n) or U_{E/F} or...) I'd love to know just basic things like: what precisely is in the discrete spectrum, what is in the tempered spectrum, what is,... I can't even find any references that really talk about the tempered spectrum at all. Even references for $G(\mathbb{R})$ are extraordinarily difficult. In theory the total Langlands classification for $G(\mathbb{R})$ is known, but it's so hard to extract any information: like is an L-packet in the discrete case just made up of things with the same central

Comment: and infinitesimal character? etc. Any prodding towards some articles in your list, or elsewhere, that might address these more specific questions would be incredibly helpful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ is a connected reductive group over a number field $F.$ Suppose that $v$ is a place for which $G(F_v)$ is not compact modulo center. Let $\pi$ be an automorphic representation of $G.$ If $\pi_v$ is one-dimensional then $\pi$ is one-dimensional. This statement appears in the appendix in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07567. I don't totally understand the proof yet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! This is indeed a simpler proof to the question that the OP originally asked (and I misinterpreted)--it was also suggested by Kimball in the comments of my answer.. What about the proof are you unsure of?